# numpy magic to clean up function

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following function in which I wish to interpolate from a table at a specified value. The trick is that the table is defined in a log-log sense such that straight lines between points in log-log are really exponential. Thus I can't really use any of the typical scipy interpolate routines.

So here's what I have:

```
PSD = np.array([[5.0, 0.001],
                [25.0, 0.03],
                [30.0, 0.03],
                [89.0, 0.321],
                [90.0, 1.0],
                [260.0, 1.0],
                [261.0, 0.03],
                [359.0, 0.03],
                [360.0, 0.5],
                [520.0, 0.5],
                [540.0, 0.25],
                [780.0, 0.25],
                [781.0, 0.03],
                [2000.0, 0.03]])

def W_F(freq):
    '''
    A line connecting two points in a log-log plot are exponential
    '''
    w_f = []
    for f in freq:
        index = np.searchsorted(PSD[:,0], f)
        if index <= 0:
            w_f.append(PSD[:,1][0])
        elif index + 1>= PSD.shape[0]:
            w_f.append(PSD[:,1][-1])
        x0 = PSD[:,0][index-1]
        F0 = PSD[:,1][index-1]
        x1 = PSD[:,0][index]
        F1 = PSD[:,1][index]
        w_f.append(F0*(f/x0)**(math.log(F1/F0)/math.log(x1/x0)))
    return np.array(w_f)
```

I'm looking for a better, cleaner, "numpy-ish" way to implement this

Comment: `for freq = in f:` - is just a transcription typo or does your code not work? Also, shouldn't you be using freq in the second to last line instead of f?

Comment: Yes, the function is incorrect. Should read:

Comment: I've corrected the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to go is to just take the logarithm of `PSD` and then use SciPy interpolation functions:

```
logPSD = numpy.log(PSD)
logW_F = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(logPSD[:,0], logPSD[:,1])
W_F = numpy.exp(logW_F(numpy.log(f)))
```

This will throw an error for out-of-bounds values.  To avoid the error, you could

- Pass `bounds_error=False` to the `interp1d()` function, see [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html).
- Add an entry at the beginning and the end of PSD with a very small and very large x-value to capture all possible values.

As an alternative to using `interp1d()`, it is possible to vectorise your code, but I would only do this for a reason.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I think the log(f) on the last line should be changed to numpy.log(f)